# Powershell script to fetch output in comma separated value in a for loop

Tags: powershell

Trying to input a  list of servers into my script using a for loop and then  would need the results in a comma separated format.

## input a list of servers

```
$s1 = (get-content .\s1.txt)
foreach($s2 in $s1){
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

    $NumberoflogicalProcessors = (gwmi win32_processor -computername $s2 |measure -Property NumberoflogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum
    $CPUCore = (gwmi win32_processor -computername $s2 |measure -Property  numberOfCores -Sum).Sum

    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPU Logical processors" -Value $NumberoflogicalProcessors
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPU Core" -Value $CPUCore
    $List+= $object
}
return $List

$str1 = "NumberoflogicalProcessors"+","+"CPUCore"
$str2 = $NumberoflogicalProcessors.ToString() + "," + $CPUCore.ToString()
return $str1 + "`n" + $str2
```

expected output:

```
row1(header)
row2(server1 values)
row2(server2 values)
```

Example:

```
NumberoflogicalProcessors, CPUCore
2, 5
4, 3
so on.......
```

Comment: Using convert-to csv or export-to*emphasized text* csv would fetch me an output in csv foramt, however I'm trying to get the values in the below format , passing them to str1(header)in row1 and str2(with respective server values) in row 2, which im unable to get, please assist

Answer (score 3):

A little bit cleaner and easier to read would be something like this:

```
$s1 = Get-Content -Path .\s1.txt
$List = foreach ($s2 in $s1) {
    $CPUCore = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Processor  -ComputerName  $s2 

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $s2
        PhysicalCores = $CPUCore.NumberOfCores
        LogicalCores  = $CPUCore.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    }
}
$List
$List | Export-Csv -Path .\s1List.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

You don't need to run the WMI or CIM cmdlet twice inside of one loop.

Comment: `-Delimiter ','` is the default, in case OP doesn't want double quotes in the csv :  `($List | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -Replace '"' | Set-Content .\s1List.csv`

Comment: All standard-compliant tools should not have a problem with the double quotes.

Comment: @Olaf, without using export-csv, is it possible to use it this way
$str1 = "NumberoflogicalProcessors"+","+"CPUCore"
$str2 = $NumberoflogicalProcessors.ToString() + "," + $CPUCore.ToString()
return $str1 + "`n" + $str2 in the loop and fetch the result?? trying to use this script in a tool and need the display of output in the above format, without exporting it to a file.

Comment: You can use the produced output in whatever way you need  ... it's totally up to you. ;-)

Comment: :-)If yes, please let me know where to place the above variables str1 and str2 in the script to get the CSV output

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Did you try the code example? What happend? What output would you expect exactly? You just have to output `$List` if you don't want to write it to a file. You might make a step back and start with learning the [very basics of Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6) to help you to understand the help you get.